# How to write a small test function using pester testing framework

Tags: azure, powershell, unit-testing, azure-devops, pester

How to write a small test function using pester testing framework

```
function SaveStudent($Student){
 Write-Host "save student email for $($Student.Email)
 return $Student 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have written a sample test function using pester frame work & tested in local environment as well.
Below is the sample Get-Something function here is the function module:

```
    function Get-Something {    
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter()]
        [string]
        $ThingToGet
    )
 
    if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('ThingToGet')) {
        Write-Output "I got $ThingToGet!"
    }
    else {
        Write-Output "I got something!"
    }
}
```

Here are the function module tests cases

```
Describe "Get-Something" {
    Context "when parameter ThingToGet is not used" {
        It "should return 'I got something!'" {
            Get-Something | Should -Be 'I got something!'
        }
    }
 
    Context "when parameter ThingToGet is used" {
        It "should return 'I got ' follow by a string" {
            $thing = 'a dog'
            Get-Something -ThingToGet $thing | Should -Be "I got $thing!"
        }
    }
}
```

For more information, you can refer this  [blog](https://jeffbrown.tech/getting-started-with-pester-testing-in-powershell/) or pester documentation to [Quick start](https://pester.dev/docs/quick-start) with pester testing frame work.